# Getting NavigatorUserMediaError while using chromeMediaSource: "desktop"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I have created a DesktopCapture extension for chrome to get chromeMediaSourceId for desktop capture.
The extension returns the chromeMediaSourceId successfully to the main html page when i run it on the localhost.

Here is what i am getting in the constrains :

```
    {
     "audio":false,
     "video":{ 
              "mandatory":{
                            "chromeMediaSource":"desktop",
                            "maxWidth":1920,"maxHeight":1080,
                            "chromeMediaSourceId":"ouIW7wIZYullGDpZid/S2w=="
                          },
              "optional":[]
            }
    }
```

But when i call

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(screen_constraints, function (stream) {
                    document.querySelector('video').src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

I am getting the following error

```
NavigatorUserMediaError {constraintName: "", message: "", name: "InvalidStateError"}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that looks odd to me is

```
    {
     "audio":false,
     "video":{ 
              "mandatory":{
                            "chromeMediaSource":"desktop",
                            "maxWidth":1920,"maxHeight":1080,
                            "chromeMediaSourceId":"ouIW7wIZYullGDpZid/S2w=="
                          },
              "optional":[]
            }
    }
```

should be

```
{
    audio:false,
    video:{ 
             mandatory:{
                           chromeMediaSource:"desktop",
                           maxWidth:1920,maxHeight:1080,
                           chromeMediaSourceId:"ouIW7wIZYullGDpZid/S2w=="
                         },
             optional:[]
           }
}
```

The difference being that audio, false, video, chromeMediaSource, ... should not be in quotes.

Comment: I am getting the same error even after changing the format. This InvalidStateError is coming in getUserMedia() only when the "chromeMediaSource":"desktop". What could be the possible reasons for this?

Comment: These are the two example files for send and receive.
https://testweb.connectuscom.com:47555/screen_send.html
https://testweb.connectuscom.com:47555/screen_receive.html